# what is ContractPromise? near-sdk-as to near-sdk-rs comparison

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I've found this function in an assemblyscript project for a NEAR contract:

```
export function assert_single_promise_success(): void {
  const x = ContractPromise.getResults()
  assert(x.length == 1, "Expected exactly one promise result")
  assert(x[0].succeeded, "Expected PromiseStatus to be successful")
}
```

What does ContractPromise.getResults() do exactly? How should implement the same thing in rust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give an answer, comments taken directly from the implementation of `ContractPromise.getResults()`, [which can be found here](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-as/blob/48e5f359d07db891977e188715c3afec028aaf16/sdk-core/assembly/contract.ts#L336). The implementation also has an example on how to use the function, which may be useful.

> Method to receive async (one or multiple) results from the remote
> contract in the callback.
>
> @returns An array of results based on the number of promises the
> callback was created on. If the callback using `then` was scheduled
> only on one result, then one result will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

here is something similar in Rust from one of the [examples in the SDK](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/de81ae5e21a406219911527ae4a622b1b3a2f633/examples/cross-contract-low-level/src/lib.rs#L70-L79) repo

```rs
require!(env::promise_results_count() == 2);

let data0: Vec<u8> = match env::promise_result(0) {
  PromiseResult::Successful(x) => x,
  _ => env::panic_str("Promise with index 0 failed"),
};
```